# emacs 24.3 on Windows 7 does not close properly

Tags: windows-7, emacs

I'm running Emacs 24.3 on a Windows 7 machine. No matter how I close the editor,
whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or the menu,
Emacs always crashes and I get the error “GNU Emacs: The extensible self-documenting text editor
has stopped working” (illustrated below).
Does anyone else get a similar error? Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?
FWIW, I had a similar error come up while using Emacs 23 as well.
I was under the impression this would go away in Emacs 24. Looks like not.
I have attached a screenshot, which [links to a full-size version of itself
[image: Emacs has stopped working]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hubJS.png).

I'm also including the complete fault message here, to further assist the trouble shooting:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: emacs.exe
  Application Version:  24.3.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    51461ed8
  Fault Module Name:    libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4bc96cad
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 00016646
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 40aa
  Additional Information 2: 40aadffc5490879468da6327c52e8317
  Additional Information 3: 30a6
  Additional Information 4: 30a67832b564ca36083716f18a2a95ef
```

Comment: Could you include the rest of the error message? It seems to be a problem with libgcc. Does the error message give you a "Faulting module path"?

Comment: @terdon, Here's the rest of the message: `Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: emacs.exe
  Application Version: 24.3.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 51461ed8
  Fault Module Name: libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4bc96cad
  Exception Code: 40000015
  Exception Offset: 00016646
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID: 2057
  Additional Information 1: 40aa
  Additional Information 2: 40aadffc5490879468da6327c52e8317
  Additional Information 3: 30a6
  Additional Information 4: 30a67832b564ca36083716f18a2a95ef
`

Comment: @terdon, as you can see above there was no "faulting module path" error in the error message. But I have attached the complete error message in the main question -- it is more clearly formatted and readable there than here. Sorry about it.

Comment: Maybe you have the same problem as this guy: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-12/msg00194.html

Comment: @jjlin,

Thanks for commenting. I used dependency walker, and was surprised to find that there was absolutely no mention of libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll. But, there are 16 libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll files in total on my machine related to various FOSS modules.

I tried pasting these dlls from 3-4 different applications, one at a time, into \bin\emacs.exe dir, but I still get the same error. I stopped this exercise at this point as it is actually not going anywhere.

Simply put, dependency walker does not show libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll! Whoa!

Comment: If you run `strings` on `emacs.exe`, that DLL is referenced, though. I'm not really familiar with all the ways libraries can be resolved and loaded on Windows, but maybe `emacs.exe` has a copy "built in" somehow, but it is preferring one of these other copies for some reason. You could perhaps test this theory by moving the 16 copies of the DLL to some place where they definitely won't be found, and then seeing if Emacs still crashes.

Comment: @jjlin, I would much rather put up with emacs crash than the headache of remembering which dll was from which module and ending up with 17 crashed applications. I'm sure you'll understand :)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem.

I solved it for my setup by passing the `--no-splash` option to emacs on start up.

I don't get a splash screen now, but I don't crash on exit either.

Comment: Like I mentioned to another one earlier, thanks for taking an interest and replying. What is interesting, is that when I moved from Win 7 Home Premium 32 bits to Win 7 Home Premium 64 bits, this crash went away! [Touch wood!] I hope this is the last I see of this error.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Also, in resp to @Surio's comment, I'm on Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit and am getting this error.

Comment: This solution stopped working when I moved to Win 10.  I had to fix  libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll as described below.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem while setting up a new Windows 7 laptop.  Checking the Windows event viewer revealed that the version of Emacs libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was linking to was the culprit.  A quick scan of my C drive with [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) resulted in no fewer than seven versions of the library scattered among various versions of MinGW that I had install alongside other apps, RStudio, OSGeo4W, CodeBlocks, etc. A couple of which had injected themselves into my system path variable.

The solution for me was to ensure Emacs found a compatible libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll or none at all by setting the PATH variable before starting Emacs.  From a command line type `set path=` to clear the path variable before starting emacs with `c:\<pathtoemacsbin>\runemacs.exe`, assuming you will not need path access to other files.  Alternatively, a recent version of MinGW32 should be compatible.  Just make sure it is available on the search path, `set path=c:\MinGW32\bin`.

Answer (score 2):

I found just one instance of libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll on my machine, installed under GNUplot.

I renamed it arbitrarily, and now emacs works fine. Of course, GNUplot doesn't, but hey!

Comment: I found just one instance of libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll on my machine, installed under GPS (GNAT Programming Studio)..

I uninstalled it, and now emacs works fine. Of course, GPS doesn't, but hey!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,  libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is statically linked so it is irrelevant the origin of the file.

I have experienced the same crashes and I can confirm two things:

- No crashes in emacs 24.3 built with gcc v3.x.x
- No crashes in emacs 24.3 built with gcc v4.5 sjlj

And this thread

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27481215

might confirm the last point.

HTH

Comment: Interesting point!  From the emacs startup page   "This is GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2013-03-18 on MARVIN". No mention of version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the crashes happen when you start without an init file (`~/.emacs`), i.e., using `emacs -Q`.  If so, you might consider filing a bug report with a reproducible recipe. If not, bisect your init file recursively until you find the culprit code.

`emacs -Q` is the place to start: (a) when reporting a problem and (b) when debugging.

Comment: thanks for taking an interest and replying. What is interesting, is that when I moved from Win 7 Home Premium 32 bits to Win 7 Home Premium 64 bits, this crash went away! [Touch wood!] I hope this is the last I see of this error.